# Using copy activity in ADF to dynamically map a child collection of objects from REST API

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to configure a single copy activity in ADF that can be used to dynamically copy and auto-create the SQL sink table (if it does not exist) for any JSON source similar to how you can create a single COPY activity to dynamically create a SQL sink table for any SQL source table I specify as the source. The JSON files will always have the dynamic content under a collection reference called "items" as shown in the screen shot from a REST preview of the dataset below.

```
[
  {
    "items": [
      {
        "FirstName": "Joe",
        "LastName": "Someone"
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "Steve",
        "LastName": "Someone"
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "Frank",
        "LastName": "Someone"
      }
    ],
    "totalResults": 3
  }
]
```

I want the mappings to be dynamic based on the fields found under this "items" collection and I don't care about the "totalResults" attribute, so I specified the collection reference on the Mappings tab.

[image]

When the copy activity runs it creates a table within a single row and a single column called "totalResults" which is NOT what I was expected.

[image]

What I wanted was for it to create a table with both the "FirstName" and "LastName" with 3 records.

[image]

Can I achieve my desired behavior with a copy activity or must this be done in a data flow?

Comment: You can click `Import schemas` in the mapping tab of copy activity. Then You can remove the `TotalResults` field from mapping by unchecking the include check box.  [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/XUJp7Kf.png)

Comment: If you do that, then it will always expect the items collection to have FirstName and LastName.  The next JSON file I pass it may have a different set of attributes under it.

Comment: you can use dataflow flatten activity to dynamically flatten the columns under items[]. [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/TpwOTHY.png)

Comment: Correct...the question is geared towards if this type of dynamic mapping can be done in a copy activity.  I'm getting the feeling like it's not.

Comment: copy activity does not map the columns automatically. hierarchical data cannot be flattened and mapped dynamically/

Comment: Yes the solution works, but I was already aware that could be done. in data flow : )  I was trying to avoid the dataflow since its more "heavy handed" than copy activity if that makes sense.  So yea... the question about whether this can be done in copy activity is answered and thank for being thorough with the data flow solution as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot do dynamically flatten and map using copy activity. You can use **Flatten transformation** in dataflow activity to dynamically flatten all the columns under `item[]`. Below are the steps.

- Take the flatten transformation after the source transformation in dataflow
- In Flatten settings, select unroll by `items[]`
- Then select `+Add mapping` and then add `rule based mapping`.
- Enter the matching condition as `true()` and give the hierarchy level as `items[]`. Name the column as `$$`.

[image]

**Output** of the flatten transformation:
[image]